# Which projection is Mapbox using

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have `UTM` coordinates, `EPSG: 25833`.
Looking at the [Mapbox documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/mapbox-data/#mapbox-map-projections) it says

> Mapbox supports the popular Web Mercator projection, and does not support any other projections. Web Mercator is a nearly conformal projection that is adopted by the vast majority of web maps and its use allows you to combine Mapbox's maps with other layers in the same projection.
>
> Commonly this projection is referred to as EPSG:900913 or EPSG:3857. See epsg.io for more information and alternative encodings.

So, I probably have to transform the `UTM` Coordinates into `Web Mercator`.
I use the [proj4js](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js) library to do that.

```
import proj4 from 'proj4';
const epsg25833 = require('epsg-index/s/25833.json');
const epsg3857 = require('epsg-index/s/3857.json');
const mapboxCoords = proj4(epsg25833.proj4, epsg3857.proj4, [point.utm_point.coordinates[0], point.utm_point.coordinates[1]]);
```

If I try to display `mapboxCoords` on the `Mapbox Map`, nothing is displayed.
However, if I transform the coordinates into `EPSG: 4326`, everything is displayed. However, its possible that the coordinates are slightly off.

```
import proj4 from 'proj4';
const epsg25833 = require('epsg-index/s/25833.json');
const epsg4326 = require('epsg-index/s/4326.json');
const mapboxCoords = proj4(epsg25833.proj4, epsg4326.proj4, [point.utm_point.coordinates[0], point.utm_point.coordinates[1]]);
```

What is the correct projection for using `Mapbox`. The documentation says its `EPSG:3857`, however, when I transform my coordinates into that `EPSG` nothing is displayed. Using `EPSG: 4326` displays at least something...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With Mapbox's mapping libraries like Mapbox GL JS and Mapbox GL Native, the maps are visually rendered in the Web Mercator Projection (EPSG:3857), however anytime you want to pass data to show on these maps, either as a Marker or GeoJSON layer then that data must be passed as WGS84 LL, ie. EPSG:4326.

Comment: Hi @AndrewHarvey, please could you provide some documentation for this answer? Specifically with regards to why the data must be passed as EPSG:4326? I'm looking to do some further reading on this topic.

Comment: @L.Youl for Mapbox GL JS anytime you pass a set of coordinates like for a Marker then LngLat https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/geography/#lnglat defines it as expected to be in WGS84 LL, ie. EPSG:4326. Anytime you create a local source if as geojson then per the GeoJSON spec https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946 "GeoJSON uses a geographic coordinate reference system, World Geodetic System 1984, and units of decimal degrees."

Comment: Just note that RFC7946 GeoJSON is not urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326 or EPSG:4326,  It's urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC::CRS84  The axis order is different.

Answer (score 1):

Mapbox supports the popular Web Mercator projection, commonly referred to as EPSG:900913 or EPSG:3857.

Mapbox docs link for reference:

- https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/mapbox-data/#mapbox-map-projections